# C# Unity, ¿Como puedo sumar variables dentro del metodo OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: c#, unity

soy Facundo.

Contexto: Veran estoy estudiando desarrollo de videojuegos por mi cuenta en Unity y C#.

Objetivo: Quiero hacer que cuando el `gameObject` colisione contra otro ambos se destruyan y despues se le sume +1 a una variable `private int score` declarada al principio como global para ser mostrada con `Debug.Log("Puntos: " + score)` y dar el total de puntos acumulados

Resultados:

- Positivos Los `gameObjects` son destruidos.
- Negativo: Se suma 1 a la var `private int score` y se muestra en consola, pero cuando vuelvo a lanzar el projectil y se vuelve a ejecutar vuelve a sumar +1 y es `score = 1` en ves de ser `score = 2` que es como deberia ser.

Muchas gracias. Les dejo el codigo, si me pueden ayudar estoy sumamente agradecido.

```
public class DetectCollides : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public int score = 0;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    
    if (other.CompareTag("Projectile"))
    {

        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        score += 1;
        Debug.Log(score);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta es que una variable 'private' es exclusiva del script que la contiene y solo dicho script puede acceder a esta misma.

Lo segundo: ¿A qué objeto tienes este script asignado? Entiendo que lo tienes en uno de los objetos. El score deberías de tenerlo en un script distinto al que detecta las colisiones y este script en un objeto que no lo vas a destruir durante toda la ejecución.
De esta forma, cuando destruyas el objeto que colisiona, no se reinicia toda la información.

Yo haría algo así (he modificado un poco tu código):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollides : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ScoreHandler scoreHandler;

    private void Start()
    {
        scoreHandler = GameObject.Find("ScoreHandlerObj").GetComponent<ScoreHandler>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.CompareTag("Projectile"))
        {

            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            scoreHandler.updateScore();
            Debug.Log(scoreHandler.getScore());

        }

    }
}
```

Y el de la puntuación:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScoreHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int score;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
    }

    public void updateScore()
    {
        score++;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

}
```

Utiliza otras alternativas a GameObject.Find si lo consideras necesario (por ejemplo buscar el objeto por 'tag').

Comment: Muchisimas gracias